# Create a bottom 3 section pane on android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create the below layout in Android? I want the bottom bar to have a fixed size and the above-panel to grow based on the device size. Is there a library that's available to have the below effect?

[image: Bottom bar]

Right now I used a relative layout but the height of the top panel doesn't grow.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.71"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_height="150dp"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/Ashok-Varma/BottomNavigation check this

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/tab_bar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="150dp"></LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set *android:layout_height="0dp"* and *android:layout_weight="1"*.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.amrizal.example.firebasetester.SecondActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
        <TextView
            android:text="Section 1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
        <TextView
            android:text="Section 2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```